# how can i fill modal with data then open it although event oncommand a linkbutton from grid view ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

How can I fill modal with data then open it although the event `oncommand` a link button from grid view  ASP.net?

Is there any I can handle this problem?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridproduct" class="table table-bordered table-striped" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Product Name"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="image" ControlStyle-Height="50px" ControlStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="Image"></asp:ImageField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkedit" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("id") %>' OnCommand="lnkedit_Command" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" class="pointt sweet-confirm" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("id") %>' OnCommand="lnkdelete_Command" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void lnkedit_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    var product = (from obj in db.RelatedService
                           where obj.ServiceId == id
                           select obj).FirstOrDefault();
    txtname.Text = product.ServiceName;
    txtdescreption.Text = product.ServiceDetailed;
    img.ImageUrl = product.Serviceimage;
    lblid.Text = id.ToString();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "openModal();", true);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now? What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: the modal dosenot even show up ???